# Building a "single page" site with animation between pages

Tags: javascript, jquery, slide, jquery-effects

I would love to know what is used to have an effect such as this website template: http://www.templatemonster.com/demo/43491.html

I would like to have a single menu and background while once I click on the menu link it triggers the new page to slide into view without being redirected to a new page causing the browser to reload the new page, etc. Something smooth and nice.

I'm not looking for code (other than the functions to use (if JQuery)) and what effects should I be looking for to make this possible?

Just point me in the right direction :)

Comment: Why not just use the source code of that page as an example?  It's all right there for you to look at.

Comment: Thank you for the title edit and I don't want to copy exactly from them and there are more than one way to skin a cat. I just want everyones input. Some people are more experienced in some areas and may say one thing while other people may say another. Maybe that template has a poor code setup and could be more efficient. Many reasons I don't use their source code as an example :)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

now there can be tons of ways .. the easy way (but it's not much of a maintainable way )

is to all your website content in one page and wrap every section that you consider a page in a div like so

```
<div class="home-page">content of home page goes here </div>
<div class="contact-us-page">content of contact us  page goes here </div>

etc...
```

and with jquery hide them all except the home page

```
$(function(){
   $('.contact-us-page').hide();
   $('.other-page').hide();
})
```

and when the user clicks on the link to other page let's say the contact us page you will hide the parent and slide the contact us page instead

```
$('.contact-us-link').click(function(){
    $('.home-page').hide(1000);
    $('.contact-us-page').show(1000);
})
```

and thats it :)

the down fall of this is that there will be no routing ..

so to solve this you have to use something like backbone.js
which takes a while to know it well ...

this is just a quick idea on how this works ..

Comment: Downsides of this, as you mentioned: not maintainable, no routing. Downsides you didn't mention: not very accessible, no fallback, not SEO. Routing doesn't require backbone.js. Now with HTML5 there are some nifty solutions!

Comment: @Sunyatasattva What do you mean by "there are some nifty solutions?" Would you mind contributing with examples of what one could do with html5 to accomplish this task? :)

Comment: I did at the end of my answer.

Comment: @Sunyatasattva , there will be seo as google crawler will not have javascript enabled so the divs will be shown to it , and it will read the content .. html5 is still not will supported so this defeats all the talk about the fallback support , and no if the user doesnt have JavaScript he will be still able to read the content and access it  .. and no the routing feature of html5 isnt a good solution at all it is still immature and not well supported .. where in the other hand backbone will work in each and every browser ! so i dont think that html5 is the answer here

Comment: @codeiz The search engine crawler will be able to see the content, but  unfortunately "seeing the content" is not the primary SEO requisite. One has to also index the content correctly: in this solution there is no separation of the content, as everything is in one page, and the pages are only virtual. So it wouldn't be possible to have different titles, urls, and so on for the pages. This could work out for a smallish portfolio-kind of site, but not at all for a blog, for example.

Comment: As for the **fallback** support, I don't see what you mean. Fallback is exactly what it sounds like: something you *fall back on* when your new technologies are not supported by your end-user. In my proposed solution, the fallback would enable you to use features not indeed supported across the board without fear of breaking usability.

Comment: you are assuming the the user doesnt have JavaScript enabled and you want fallback ?! to what ?! and that assumption ist very valid these days IMHO

Comment: You **fallback** to a normally working webpage. Since your **target URL** is still in your `href`, it can still be crawled, but, more importantly, accessed with a click on the link on a browser with JS disabled.

Comment: As for the backbone.js thing, backbone used to use **hashbangs** to route, which, [has been pointed out](http://isolani.co.uk/blog/javascript/BreakingTheWebWithHashBangs) many times as [bad practice](http://www.ubergizmo.com/2012/02/twitter-working-to-get-rid-of-hashbang-urls/); both in SEO, long-term thinking, and usability. [Now even backbone has switched to basically use the **history API**](http://zachlendon.github.com/blog/2012/02/21/backbone-dot-js-from-hashbangs-to-pushstate/).

Comment: Finally, you don't really need backbone.js (which is awesome) just for that. If you want this kind of page we are speaking about to work the way you are talking about, just go ahead and use `location.hash` which is supported by all major browsers.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to achieve what you wish, but this is my suggestion on how to go about it conceptually:

1. Animate the content by **animating the `position`** of your content container, that should give a nice smooth feeling to your page. [The jQuery documentation](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) should be pretty clear on that. Remember that you want to intercept the normal behaviour of the anchor, so either [`preventDefault()`](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/) or `return false`, or both.
2. **Get your content using an [AJAX request](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)**. You can use the `href` attribute that you put in your link in order to fetch the correct content. Then bind an event to that `<a>` element with a the [`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) method. The reason why you leave the `href` is to have a graceful fallback: should something go wrong with the code, should the user have javascript disabled, or simply navigating on a non-javascript friendly browser, he will still be able to access your content.

These are the two essential steps to achieve what you are looking for. If you want to fine tune your site a bit more, try to think about those things as well:

1. **Make your website look more responsive** by the cautious use of loading `.gif`s.
2. **Don't double serve content:** check whether the user is clicking to the link of the currently displaying page and don't fetch the content again; besides looking silly to your user, it will make a useless server load (probably insignificant, but still). Always consider your user, though! Tell him that that link is disabled by clever use of UI.
3. **Manipulate browser history:** using the [history API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history). Your site will be more accessible, more user-friendly, more SEO-friendly, and will also look much more advanced.

Comment: I wish I were more advanced to know what you were meaning by this but I will try to come and look back at your answer later on once I have a better understanding of what you were saying. Thank you for the contribution to the question though!

Comment: What is that you need more help with? Or something that is unclear?

Comment: I just do not understand all of JQuery yet, I've been taking online lessons though that are helping me understand the syntax and all of the documentation. For example, I have no clue what "intercepting the normal behavior of the anchor" would mean, nothing you can help with right now.. I simply need to continue learning (I've been learning JQuery for only 3 days for a few hours at a time.)

Comment: I do know HTML very well and CSS so don't worry, I'm not jumping ahead ;) I just figured I'd make my pages more "interactive" or "playful" with smooth animations and other features JQuery can do.

Comment: Keep playing, that's the best way to learn. By the way, *"intercepting the normal behavior of the anchor"* means that, normally, clicking an *anchor* (`<a>` element) will redirect the user to its `href` attribute (i.e. clicking a link brings you somewhere else). With javascript you can prevent this behavior and do other things on clicking of the link instead of making the browser load a new page.

Comment: I understand what you're saying now

Comment: I am glad; feel free to ask if you need further clarification. I don't know the reason why of the downvote, I guess it was by the other answerer with whom we argued over a few points; it is unfortunate he didn't bother to comment why should my answer be downvoted. There are a few drawbacks to your accepted answer, so good for practice but be careful using it in a real-world environment!